# Running local python files on remote server

Tags: python, ssh, import, cat

In order to run a local python script on remote server, I use the following command:

```
cat hello.py | ssh user@192.168.1.101 python -
```

But when I want to run a script which imports some files;

```
import _init_paths
from fast_rcnn.config import cfg
from fast_rcnn.test import im_detect
from fast_rcnn.nms_wrapper import nms
```

the above command doesn't solve my problem. How can I run such a python file on remote server?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you able to scp the files directly to the server and work from there? That seems like it would be the easiest option.

Comment: I have to run the python file in the server, and get the output in raspberry pi. Raspberry pi has not enough capability to run the python file.

Comment: Are there any repeated functions, methods, etc? It is a bit rough but you could do (cat file1.py & cat file2.py & cat ...) | shh ... to compile all of the files into one large script. This should give the expected results.

Comment: I cannot do something like cat folder_name/ |ssh... ???

Comment: cat only works for files afaik, and even if you could, it could read them in the wrong order.